# Notation, Describing Components of Matrices

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm working on my Master Thesis and have a hard time precisely describing some matrices which are put together in an odd way. I wanted to ask for some help in order to not do any mistakes here.

Generally, my matrix has the dimensions as follows

$$
\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times 2+2J}
$$

This matrix consits of $2+2J$ variables or arrays with a length of $M$. Two variables are scalars that I refere to throughout my thesis:

$$
R_d \in \mathbb{R}^{1}, \quad 
g \in \mathbb{R}^{1}
$$

However, two other variables themselves are arrays with$J$ variables. They are given with:

$$
\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^{J}, \quad 
\mathbf{q} \in \mathbb{R}^{J}
$$

Now I would like to mathematically describe how $\mathbf{X}$ is structured. I thought one could describe it as follows:

$$
\mathbf{X} = [Rd\; g \; \mathbf{p}\; \mathbf{q} ] \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times 2+2J}
$$

I'm not sure if this is mathematically correct since I'm missing the first dimension in the member variables. Is there a better notation to describe the structure of $\mathbf{X}$? What happens when the dimensions need to be flipped? I would assuem that when I list the members in square brackets, this would relate to the first dimension $M$ instead of $2 + 2J$.

An alternative description might look like this:

$$
\mathbf{X} = [R_{d,m}\; g_m \; \mathbf{p}_m\; \mathbf{q}_m ] \in \mathbb{R}^{2+2J \times M}
$$

with $g_m \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$ or $\mathbf{q}_m in \mathbb{R}^{M \times J}$. (Also flipped the dimensions of $\mathbf{X}$.) Would this be a more precise notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is commonly referred to as a block matrix.
$$
X = \bigg[ 
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
P & Q & \mathbf{r}  & \mathbf{g}
\end{array}
\bigg]
$$
with matrices $P\in{\mathbb{R}^{m\times j}}$ and $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times j}$, and vectors $r\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $g\in\mathbb{R}^m$

If you are writing for an audience that is unfamiliar with this notation you could add the verbose but explicit:

$$
X = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc|c|c}
p_{11} &p_{12} &\cdots & p_{1j} & 
 q_{11} &q_{12} &\cdots & q_{1j} &
 r_1 & g_1
 \\
p_{21} &p_{22} &\cdots &p_{2j} & 
 q_{21} &q_{22} &\cdots &q_{2j} &
 r_2 & g_2
 \\ 
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots &
 \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots &
 \vdots & \vdots
 \\
p_{m1} & p_{m2} & \cdots & p_{mj} &
 q_{m1} & q_{m2} & \cdots & q_{mj} &
 r_m & g_m
\end{array}
\right]
$$

For more examples on how to write block matrices, see:
[https://wp.kntu.ac.ir/hadizadeh/pdf/latex/lesson_12[1].pdf](https://wp.kntu.ac.ir/hadizadeh/pdf/latex/lesson_12%5B1%5D.pdf)